# Splitting rows into ranges

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula, unpivot

I have a google sheet with data that looks like this:

```
StudentA  Module1  Grade1  Module2  Grade2
StudentB  Module1  Grade1  Module2  Grade2
```

i want to split it using a formula to look like this:

```
StudentA Module1 Grade1
StudentA Module2 Grade2
StudentB Module1 Grade1
StudentB Module2 Grade2
```

What I tried was to combine each row into a string that looks like this (one cell):

```
StudentA:Module1:Grade1
StudentA:Module2:Grade2
```

The newline is generated by using char(10) concatenated. Then on another sheet I refer to the whole table of values (with multiple students) and split it using =arrayformula(split(data,":")).
All it did was to make it look like the original table but with names repeated in each row:

```
StudentA  Module1  Grade1  StudentA Module2  Grade2
StudentB  Module1  Grade1  StudentB Module2  Grade2
```

Any ideas, anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the case preseted in the question, the required result could be achieved by using the Google Sheets way to handle arrays

Example

```
={A2:C3;A2:A3,D2:E3}
```

You could combine the above with other functions like SORT.

NOTE:

If your spreadsheet use comma as decimal separator, in the above formula instead of comma use `\`.

Reference

- [Using arrays in Google Sheets](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/6208276?hl=en)